# Why gcc linker instead of ld.lld is invoked when target is specified in clang command?

Tags: clang, llvm, lld

Helllo,

On my WSL2 ubuntu 20.04 system, when I use the following command to invoke ld.lld, everything is OK:

```
clang -fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld.lld ....
```

But when the option "--target=aarch64" is added, it will invoke gcc.

```
clang -fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld.lld --target=aarch64
```

The actual command will be:

```
'/usr/bin/gcc' -fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld.lld --target=aarch64
```

Note: when I run the below command, it shows:

```
simon@LAPTOP-JH2M71LG:~/musl-1.2.2$ clang -fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld.lld --target=aarch64 -v obj/src/unistd/writev.lo 
clang version 13.0.0 
Target: aarch64 
Thread model: posix 
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin 
"/usr/bin/gcc" -fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld.lld -o a.out obj/src/unistd/writev.lo 
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld.lld’ 
clang-13: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note: At the same time I have link edthe ld to ld.lld by using following command:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/local/bin/ld.lld /usr/bin/ld
```

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: *"The actual command will be"* How did you determine it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I add the information about it, thanks!

Comment: Why is this a problem? FWIW, if you're asking about why, the reason it's done is that gcc contains a tediously long table of flags and libraries to use on different platforms, and the llvm maintainers are too cowardly/lazy/smart/… to put in the work to duplicate all that. Instead they sometimes use gcc to invoke ld with the right flags.